# How to reset SIGINT to default after pointing it some user-defined handler for some time?

Tags: c++, signals

I use `signal(SIGINT,my_handler)` to point `SIGINT` to `my_handler`. After some time I want to reset it to whatever default handler it points to in general. How can I do that?

Comment: Think of porting your code to use [`sigaction()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html) which among other things allows saving old signal handing configuration and later properly restoring it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pass `SIG_DFL` as the `func` parameter to `signal()` to reset default behaviour:

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Today, the usage of [sigaction](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html) is recommended.

Moreover, it allows you to reset automatically the signal handler to default one before your custom handler is called the first time.

> `SA_RESETHAND`
>
> If set, the disposition of the signal shall be reset to `SIG_DFL` and the
>   `SA_SIGINFO` flag shall be cleared on entry to the signal handler.
>
> *Note:
>   `SIGILL` and `SIGTRAP` cannot be automatically reset when delivered; the system
>   silently enforces this restriction.*
>
> Otherwise, the disposition of the signal shall not be modified on entry to the
>   signal handler.
>
> In addition, if this flag is set, `sigaction()` may behave as if the `SA_NODEFER`
>   flag were also set.

### Defining a one time signal handler

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

action.sa_handler = my_handler;
action.sa_flags   = SA_RESETHAND;

if (sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL) == -1)
{
  perror("Failed to install signal handler for SIGINT");
}
```

Refer to this post to see how to reset a signal handler to the default one if it's not a one-time handler using sigaction:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24804019/7044965