# reset sigaction to default

Tags: c, linux, signals, bionic

In Android the bionic loader sets a default signal handler for every process on statrtup:

```
void debugger_init()
{
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = debugger_signal_handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO;
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);

    sigaction(SIGILL, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGABRT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGSTKFLT, &act, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &act, NULL);
}
```

I would like to set it back to its default, meaning I want to ignore these signal and that the default handler will take place (CORE DUMP)

How do I revert the action performed ? I want to ignore all these as if the above function never was called

Answer (score 4):

Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) and perhaps [signal(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html).

You could call

```
signal(SIGILL, SIG_DFL);
signal(SIGABRT, SIG_DFL);
```

and so on early in  your `main` (which is entered after dynamic loading)

You could also use `sigaction`  with `sa_handler`  set to `SIG_DFL`

<sup>Of course, things are more tricky if you want to default handle these signals before your `main`, e.g. in some static constructor!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I found it could lead unexpected behavior when mixed using sigaction and signal to set for one process.

Answer (score 0):

From signal(2) posted above(wouldn't surprise me if this warning wasn't there 8 years ago):

> WARNING: the behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions,
> and has also varied historically across different versions of
> Linux.  Avoid its use: use sigaction(2) instead.

Looking at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/tlib-49639/index.html

```
int pthread_sigmask(int how, const sigset_t *new, sigset_t *old);
```

> When the value of *new* is NULL, the value of *how* is not significant and the signal mask of the thread is unchanged. So, to inquire about currently blocked signals, assign a NULL value to the *new* argument.

So I guess you could use that to get the current sigmask and just wipe each one

```
sigset_t tempSet;
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, NULL, &tempSet);
sigdelset(&tempSet, /*Signal you don't want to handle*/);
sigdelset(&tempSet, /*repeat for each signal*/);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &tempSet, NULL);
```

It's pretty much the same thing with sigact to query the current action for a signal, from sigaction(2)

> sigaction() can be called with a NULL second argument to query
> the current signal handler.

It's not clear to me the ramifications of, in my case, having SIGKILL in the first call to sigaction

```
struct sigaction sigAct;
sigaction(SIGKILL, NULL, &sigAct);
sigAct.sa_handler = SIG_DFL;    // Ensure default handling of Kill signal
sigaction(/*Signal you don't want to handle*/, &sigAct, NULL);
sigaction(/*repeat for each signal*/, &sigAct, NULL);
```

Using siggetmask is obsolete by sigprocmask, and sigprocmask is only for single threaded environments.